# ViewModel is empty on Add [HttpPost] method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have following `ViewModel`:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorySelectItems
    {
        get { var ret = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if(Categories==null)
            return ret;

            ret.AddRange(Categories.Where(x => (Category == null || x.Id != 
                        Category.Id)).Select(category => new SelectListItem 
                                     { Text = category.Name, Value = 
                                        category.Id.ToString()}));
            return ret;
        }
    }

    public CategoryViewModel(){}
}
```

Following is Controller:

```
namespace mysite.com.Controllers{
    public class CategoryController : Controller{
        private IRepository<Category> _repository;
        private IRepository<Product> _productRepo;
        private CategoryViewModel _categoryViewModel;

        public CategoryController(){
            _repository = new CategoryRepository();
            _productRepo = new ProductRepository();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(){
           return View(new CategoryViewModel{Categories=_repository.GetAll()});
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Add(){
            return View(new CategoryViewModel{
           Category = new Category(), Categories= _repository.GetAll()});
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(CategoryViewModel category){
            if (ModelState.IsValid){
                _repository.Save(category.Category);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(category);
        }
    }
}
```

This is code in my view:

```
@model mysite.com.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Category", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Category</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Category.Id)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Category.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Category.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Category.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Category.ParentCategory)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ParentCategory", 
                     Model.CategorySelectItems,"--select parent category--")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Category.Name)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

But in my controller's `[HttpPost] Add` method the `category` object (of type `CategoryViewModel`) is empty :(

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your model shouldn't have complex objects associated with it... the serializer/ deserializer does not work well in those cases.  Your `Category` object should be flattened, or make your model implement `ICategory`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are returning a value too quickly:

```
if(Categories==null)
        **return ret;**

        ret.AddRange(Categories.Where(x => (Category == null || x.Id != 
                    Category.Id)).Select(category => new SelectListItem 
                                 { Text = category.Name, Value = 
                                    category.Id.ToString()}));
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your model is not deserializable.  Your model can only deserialize primitive properties and collections of primitive properties without a lot of help, and the help is usually not worth it.

Your models should look something like this:

```
public class CategoryAddModel
{
    //these values are used to populate the view, but will not deserialize
    public IList<Category> AvailableCategories { get; set; }

    //these values are deserializable
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}
    public string CategoryName {get;set;}
    public int ParentCategory {get;set;}
}

public class CategoryIndexModel
{
    public IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

your `Add.cshtml` view would look something like this:

```
@model mysite.com.ViewModels.CategoryAddModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Category</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CategoryId)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CategoryName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CategoryName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CategoryName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Category.ParentCategory)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ParentCategory", 
                new SelectList(Model.AvailableCategories, "Id", "Name"),
                "--select parent category--")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ParentCategory)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

your `Index.cshtml` view should resemble this:

```
@model mysite.com.ViewModels.CategoryIndexModel
@Html.ActionLink("Add Category", "Add")
<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model.Categories)
{
    <li> @{ // List your categories, hyperlinks to editing pages } </li>
}
</ul>
```

your `CategoryController.cs` should look like this:

```
namespace mysite.com.Controllers{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        private IRepository<Category> _repository = new CategoryRepository();
        private IRepository<Product> _productRepo = new ProductRepository();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new CategoryIndexModel
            {
                Categories=_repository.GetAll()
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult Add()
        {
            var model = new CategoryAddModel()
            {
                AvailableCategories = _repository.GetAll()
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(CategoryAddModel model){
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //TODO: (varies based on your repository model)
                //create a Category object from the model and persist it here.

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            //the complex collection does not return with the model; repopulate it here.
            model.AvailableCategories = _repository.GetAll()
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

This should get you in the general area of what you're looking for.